# ansible tower "msg": "ntlm: Bad HTTP response returned from server. Code 403",

Tags: email, ansible-tower

I have ansible version 2.9.18. Trying to send the email notification when deployment job completed. When I execute the template, it will call the mail module .yaml file.
But getting below error while executing the mail module:

[image]

Below is the mail module configuration for reference:

[image]

However I'm able to execute other tasks on the same server like installing the chrome or other agents. I'm wondering whats wrong while calling the mail module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were using only host name alone and tried with IP address as well.

**Solution**:
We have to use server name with full fqdn name (Ex: servername.sampledomain.com)
This helped us to overcome this error.

The other issue was "ansible_shell_type: powershell" was mentioned in the code level. After committing that line helped us to over come power shell related error.